# why is Intellisense not working in my VS Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am working on vs code. When I open any folder the IntelliSense is not working when I hover the mouse over any text. It was working before but now I don't know why it's not working. Kindly help...
[image: imagereference]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Write "`OmniSharp: Select Project`" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Choose the solution workspace entry.
4. Then enable the C# extension for "`OmniSharp : Project`"

**Solution 2 :**

1. Selecting a project.json-file is opening a DNX-project and VSCode will load that project plus the referenced projects.
2. Selecting a *.sln-file is opening a MSBuild-project. It will load the referenced *.csproj-projects and sibling or descendant project.json-files but no other project files that are referenced from the solution file.
3. Selecting a folder will make VSCode scan for *.sln and project.json files and VSCode will attempt to load them all.
   More info see: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/1889

**Solution 3:**

1. Download [C# v1.24.0](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp) extension can fix the IntelliSense for you

**Solution 4:**
For bootstrap and HTML IntelliSense, add the following extensions:

- HTML [HTML CSS Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css)
- [IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion)

---

**NOTE :**
All solutions need to close your VS and reopen it again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...i tried to do this it is still not working :(

Comment: @PranitaJoglekar Have you tried to close your project and reopen it again (close all tabs then close the VS) ? try to do that and clear the cash

Comment: Solution 3 worked for me!

Comment: is it bug or what ?

Answer (score 2):

For me solution 2 worked.
C# IntelliSense did not work with C# Extension v1.25.0.
Solution involved:

1. Download the old version of C# Extension 1.24.4 [vsix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp)
2. Install vsix manually to VS Code:

- Open VS Code.
- Open the “Extensions” sidebar (you can use
  “Ctrl+Shift+X”).
- Click on the ellipsis icon in the top right corner
  of the menu.
- Select “Install from VSIX…” VS Code will open a
  document browser.
- VS Code will now begin the installation
  process of the extension.

This happened to me on 2 separate machines

Comment: You dont need to use vsix, just install older version from standard extensions dialog

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace.for.Book;
```

Instead of automatically assuming a broken installation, lets start with something incredibly basic.

Book is probably a custom class you've created that you've not imported.

Tertiary to this, I've noticed that autocomplete doesn't work for List objects unless I have "using System.Collections.Generic;" as  part of my imports. Why? I've honestly no clue why it will allow my to use a List without erroring but then be completely unable to find the inferred types for autocomplete, most likely a performance based (intentional) limitation to the autocomplete to reduce the amount of data it has to pull up.

Hope this helps because I certainly couldn't find this solution, just blundered my way into it.

(This is an educated guess based on the fact that the *only* portion of text in your code that can bring up another class that's not built-in is Book)

Answer (score 1):

This question was one of the first search hits for me when I noticed IntelliSense had stopped working for C# in VSCode for me.

I'm posting my experience here in the hopes it will resolve the problem for someone else.

I figured out that starting the compile server was getting an error loading `hostfxr` when it attempted to start.

Apparently there was some issue related to this recently, but I couldn't figure out how to apply [the fix mentioned in this message](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/391#issuecomment-1684483731).

What fixed it for me was when I **uninstalled *all* C# / DotNet related VSCode extensions**. **Closed VSCode**, **reopened the project** and then allowed it to automatically install recommended extensions and download the needed libraries and tools.

Comment: There is also this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47995468/vscode-c-sharp-go-to-definition-f12-not-working

Comment: also related to a lot of unexpected behaviour people have been observing recently: [What changed about the C# extension for VS Code's IntelliSense in the v2.0.320 release?](/q/76850403/11107541)