# Language features have disappeared in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have not installed any new extensions for a while, but **all my language features have been disappeared** from VSCode. I've narrowed down the problem by disabling all plugins, except the C/C++ IntelliSense (see screenshot below), but the effect is the same.

*Update #3: Python, JavaScript, PHP and C# works, C/C++ functions work, variables not, Rust does not work at all.*

[image]

I have upgraded, re-enabled, restarted, rebooted, reinstalled everything. Both of my machines (Windows11, MacOS) produce the same symptoms, so there must be a - hopefully - trivial configuration error around the Language Server.

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about how Language Server works, and it's hard to find information. Where can I check some logs or get status of the running server(s), to see some hints on the error?

Comment: Check this : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70876161/why-is-intellisense-not-working-in-my-vs-code/70876301#70876301

Comment: @Fadi they just edited to say that C# works.

Comment: Narrowed down to C++ and Rust - the two languages I use at work and home, repectively.

Comment: Does VSCode detect that file as a rust file? fi not, try `ctrl + shift + p` and type "Change Language Mode", and click rust

Comment: Good question. Yes, it detects that it's Rust, syntax highlighting is okay, formatter is working.

Comment: Rust has shown conflict with a few plugins so try to remove all to test if that's the case

Comment: Removed all the plugins, except the examined language, no change

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Rust extension
   go to settings.json in .vscode and check rust-analyzer.enable = true
2. GO to Preferences -> File associations and check for this line
   "*.rs": "rust"
3. Also in preferences settings try Reset to default option (worked for me many times)

Answer (score 0):

**C/C++**

**Solution**

1. Check the VSCode settings: Ensure that the appropriate settings for C/C++  are configured correctly in VSCode.

   1. Install C/C++ IntelliSense Extensions in VS Code
   2. Install C/C++ Extension Pack in VS Code
   3. Configure the IntelliSense settings: Press Ctrl+Shift+P (or Cmd+Shift+P on macOS) to open the Command Palette and search for select "C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)". To edit the c_cpp_properties.json file.
      [image]
   4. IntelliSense configuration

   Refer to the document for [IntelliSense configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/configure-intellisense-crosscompilation)

   **Example c_cpp_properties.json for ubuntu**

   {
   "configurations": [
   {
   "name": "Linux",
   "includePath": [
   "${workspaceFolder}/**"
   ],
   "defines": [],
   "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
   "cStandard": "c17",
   "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
   "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
   }
   ],
   "version": 4
   }

   **Example c_cpp_properties.json for windows**

   {
   "configurations": [
   {
   "name": "Win32",
   "includePath": [
   "${workspaceFolder}/**"
   ],
   "defines": [],
   "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
   "cStandard": "c11",
   "cppStandard": "c++17",
   "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"
   }
   ],
   "version": 4
   }

   5. Restart Visual Studio Code. If it is not work Restart the system
   6. After restarting VS Code or System it also does not work. Check the IntelliSense cache: Sometimes the IntelliSense cache can become corrupted and cause issues with language features. You can try clearing the cache by opening the Command Palette (press Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P) and searching for "C/C++: Rescan workspace" or "C/C++: Reset IntelliSense Database" or "C/C++: Restart IntelliSense for Active File".
   7. Again Restart the VS Code

**Rust**

**Solution**

1. Install the rust-analyzer extension in VS Code
2. Rust and IntelliSense configuration
   Refer to the document for [IntelliSense configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/rust#_2-install-the-rustanalyzer-extension)
3. Restart the VS Code or System
4. After restarting VS Code or System it also does not work. Restart the rust analyzer. You can give by opening the Command Palette (press Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P) and searching for "rust-analyzer: Reload workspace" or "rust-analyzer: Restart Workspace".

[image]

5. Again Restart the VS Code.

**If none of these steps work, you may need to seek additional help from the VSCode community or support team.**

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).