# VS Code C# is not detecting errors other than format errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code for my C# codes, basically my little projects. I have C# extension installed and it used to be working fine.

I have .NET 7.0.201 as default SDK but also I have 7.0.1 and 6.0.4 installed at the same time.

But lately I have noticed that, the extension is not detecting any other errors, only format errors are detected and warned.

[No_Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M60Dx.png)

You see, the variable `n` is not even declared.

And here is the Output of OmniSharp:

[Omni](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPDAB.png)

Here are the list of extensions I've installed:
[ext1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SPj9.png)[ext2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0xHZ.png)

And some settings related to OmniSharp

[setting1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM3ZJ.png)[setting2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6m15L.png)[setting3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFb7V.png)

I have tried reinstalling C# extension, restart omnisharp server, but no luck.

I found it was that OmniSharp is not loading the my solution file or project file. (Once the project is loaded, it should show the project/solution name next to the fire logo at the bottom left. But it's not). I have tried selecting `.sln` file or `.csproj` to OmniSharp but it just not showing errors.

I was expecting it highlight the error as I code. Any advice would be great!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70876161/11107541 ?

Comment: i don't know what is causing the problem, i delete the folder and create a new project through console. And everything is working fine again.